# Google Maps Android v1 API deprecated - Obtaining API Key for development

Tags: android, google-maps, maps

I have several published Android apps with MapView. I have just tried to set up another computer for development, and I am finding out that Version 1 of the Google Maps Android API has been officially deprecated as of December 3rd, 2012, and from March 18th, 2013 API key cannot be requested for this version. Any suggestion how to continue developing my apps, without switching to Google Maps Android API v2 ? Thanks :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the API key is bound to APK signing key, the question boils down to signing keys.

For release APKs, you should in any case be using the same keystore for signing newer versions of old apps, so there's no problem there.

For development APKs, you can copy the debug keystore (`~/.android/debug.keystore` or `%USERPROFILE%\.android\debug.keystore`) from your old development computer to the new one. This gives you more time to migrate to the new API.

Comment: @laalto,
hi, I have a question, will the v1 map appear for my version update signed apk, if I generate it using the same KeyStore used previous version, but change my system, its shows map with debug build from new system?? I have to update the version soon, and cant convert the code for v2 map, as I have many functionalities in my custom map v1

Comment: I found its not appears, but I have the map key for previous system, to be set in xml file...

Answer (score -1):

You can't. You have to use the newer (the latest) version of the API, as the API will be "shutdown" after 3 years (as of Google's API deprecation policy).